# How to make infinite scroll in Flutter with Laravel API

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am trying to connect flutter with laravel API.
I wrote my function in Laravel Controller.

```
public function posts()
{
    $data = Posts:all()->paginate(4);

return response()->json([
  'data'    => $data,
], 200);
}
```

my JSON data:

```
{
   "data":{
      "current_page":1,
      "data":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "Title":"Post one",
            "image":"\/images\/1611417847.5061.webp",
            "created_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26",
            "updated_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "Title":"Post two",
            "image":"\/images\/1611417847.5061.webp",
            "created_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26",
            "updated_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "Title":"Post three",
            "image":"\/images\/1611417847.5061.webp",
            "created_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26",
            "updated_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "Title":"Post four",
            "image":"\/images\/1611417847.5061.webp",
            "created_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26",
            "updated_at":"2021-02-02 20:57:26"
         },
      ],
      "first_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/posts?page=1",
      "from":1,
      "last_page":4,
      "last_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/posts?page=4",
      "next_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/posts?page=2",
      "path":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/posts",
      "per_page":4,
      "prev_page_url":null,
      "to":4,
      "total":16
   }
}
```

I am new to flutter, so would you explain me how to make infinite scroll in Flutter with Laravel Paginate API.